# Интернет в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, wan

Интернет раздаётся через Ideco (компьютер другой). Добавил туда ПК с Убунту, в Убунту вбил мак и адрес ip4. Указанный в настройках локальный шлюз работает/пингуется, а второй, через который собственно идёт интернет - нет. Хотя в винде с аналогичными настройками всё пашет, в чем проблема может быть?

Answer (score 1):

Локальный шлюз, это который на Ubuntu? Второй шлюз находится за Ideco? Если так, то проверьте корректность внесения компика в проксю (ideco). Как именно вы внесли комп с Ubuntu в Ideco?

---

Удалось победить?

Comment: Нет, оба на Ideco, первый для локалки, через второй инет идёт, там несколько сетевух.Комп внёс, как и остальные виндовые - вбил его IP, указал подходящее имя и логин. Логин обычно рандомный, в данном случае как у админа Убунту поставил.

Comment: Зачем вбивается мак? Какой адрес задан на компе с Убунту? Шлюз какой указан? посмотрите маршруты какие на убунту прописаны.

Comment: Самое интересное, что до этого, когда временно давали на него доступ, всё работало. Шлюз первый, для локалки, написано в вопросе же. Насчет маршрутов не понял, что имеется в виду?

Comment: А временно включали тоже через Ideco? Не может быть конфликт правил (сори не работал с Ideco)? Маршруты на подключаемом компе, в убунту - терминал - route print (вывод сюда).Как вариант может быть терминал - netstat -n -r

Comment: выложил комбинированную версию, надеюсь так тоже понятно netstat -rТаблица маршутизации ядра протокола IPDestination Gateway Genmask Flags MSS Window irtt Iface192.168.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1link.local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1

Comment: а вывод с рабочего компа, выходящего через ideco можно сюда (route print).

Comment: Активные маршруты:Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.11       20        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.0.11    192.168.0.11       20     192.168.0.11  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.0.11    192.168.0.11       20        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     192.168.0.11    192.168.0.11       20

Comment: продолжение   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.0.11    192.168.0.11       1

Comment: попробуйте добавить маршрут в Ubuntu 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 (можно через GUI NetworkManager).для начала можно попробовать сделать route -F (очистить старую таблицу маршрутизации).